# What is the history of the vertical bar symbol |

Tags: probability, notation, history

The vertical bar symbol is used for the conditional probability. For example $$P (A|B) = \frac {P (\text {$A $ and $B $})}{P (B)}$$

The symbol is also used in describing likelihood $$L (\theta | x) = P(x | \theta) $$

What is the history behind both these uses? Who used it first and where does it come from?

Comment: Harold Jeffreys introduced the vertical bar notation for conditional probability. I will look for some references.

Comment: https://www.bayesianspectacles.org/the-man-who-rewrote-conditional-probability/

Comment: The link given by @GordonSmyth includes all the references I know on this.  My guess is that the extension to likelihood and indeed much else follows, but I don't have precise references there.

Comment: Just to be pedantic: it is probably better style to write $P(A \mid B)$ with `P(A \mid B)` rather than $P(A | B)$ with `P(A | B)`